# SQL sum columns depend on the value of other column

Tags: sql-server, lookup

I've got a table with fields:

```
Doc_No , Doc_Type , Item_No , Added_Qty ,Deducted_Qty
```

I need a query returning a result set based on

- `if  Doc_Type= "2"  then select sum(Added_Qty) AS SUM_Added_Qty`
- `if  Doc_Type= "7"  then select sum(Deducted_Qty) AS SUM_Deducted_Qty`

and show `SUM_Added_Qty - SUM_Deducted_Qty AS Stock`

the result must be on same row

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| Item_No  |  SUM_Added_Qty |  SUM_Deducted_Qty | Stock|
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks for the help!

(System is Sql server)

Comment: What do you mean "System is Sql"? Is it MySQL, Oracle, SQL-Server, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Item_No,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Doc_Type = '2' THEN Added_Qty ELSE 0 END) SUM_Added_Qty,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Doc_Type = '7' THEN Deducted_Qty ELSE 0 END) SUM_Deducted_Qty,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Doc_Type = '2' THEN Added_Qty
                 WHEN Doc_Type = '7' THEN -Deducted_Qty
                 ELSE 0 END) Stock
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Item_No
```

Comment: Thanks alot :)
i want to add more field
 SUM(CASE WHEN Doc_Type = '2' THEN Added_Qty
                 WHEN Doc_Type = '7' THEN -Deducted_Qty - Requested_Qty
                 ELSE 0 END) Stock
but it result 0